# How get back to the last command input postion in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

You want to view the return information of the last command from the beginning, because that information is relatively long. If I look for it manually, it will be very troublesome. So if I want to quickly go back to where typed last time,.
There are alternatives, of course

1. Use "less" or "more" program to make the message shorter
2. Use the history function to re-enter the command

However, the two solutions have their own problems."less" and "more" are not provided in the PowerShell, and they need to be provided additionally. In addition, sometimes the command has been executed and cannot be added  "less" or "more" again. If you re-enter the command, you may not get the same result as last time.

It can't be found in the' cursor movement functions' of 'psreadline'. You can't find the result by Google searching for 'PowerShell return to last input position'.

It seems that this demand is very basic. Is there really no way to realize it?

Comment: Would copying output to a file with `Tee-Object` work?

Comment: @vonPryz
Thank you for telling me about this alternative